# How to send Stripe Tokens to our Server from android application?

Tags: php, android, token, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe on Android and I have imported a GitHub project from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android

I did not understand how to send the generated tokens to my server after my card is validated. I found some codes but they were not helpful.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe is very easy payment gateway for implementation.

- Very first you have to create Stripe Token from your Android App.
- After generating token, you have to get TokenId from that token. for that you can use "id" key and save this as a Sting form JSON which was given by stripe:

**JSON example** :

```
com.stripe.model.Token JSON: {
  "id": "tok_189gBz2eZvKYlo2Cm2Z3qsT2",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_189gBz2eZvKYlo2CBZAUeFKj",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "cvc_check": null,
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 8,
    "exp_year": 2017,
    "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": null,
  "created": 1462907211,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

In above example **"id": "tok_189gBz2eZvKYlo2Cm2Z3qsT2"** is your TokenId.

- Now save this TokenId as a String and pass it to your back-end PHP/.net/Java server using web services. simply create one post service in which you can send this TokenId and other optional details about payment. and you can call this web service using **Retrofit** or **volley** .
- You need one web service form your back-end. so create one web-service using PHP or whatever you use for back-end.and pass this String to server.

Comment: At very first how to create Stripe Token from Android can you explain a little? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you already have a Stripe token, you can just get the token ID (`Token#getId()`), which is just a `String` and send it to your server however you like. (Wrap it in JSON, etc)

That token ID is all you need to make a charge. There are plenty of libraries that can help you with your IO needs, such as [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) and [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).